# Is this code capable of generating Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a piece of code which generates a string of length 50 to 100 with random characters

the code is :

```
CharLIST = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890')
def NEW(id_len):
    _id = ''
    while len(_id) < id_len:
        _id += random.choice(CharLIST)
    return _id
NEW(random.randint(50, 100))
```

I expect it to generate a completely random string which is not unpredictable
I used a code analyser which said it is not Cryptographically Secure
but it generate random strings which I think are unpredictable based on seeing 200 results

Comment: As a side note, `CharLIST` could be replace with `string.ascii_letters + string.digits`.

Comment: `I think are unpredictable based on seeing 200 results` the entire point of `random` is that  what it produces is deterministic and completely predictable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, none of the utilities in [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) should be considered secure. Their output is completely deterministic.
This is emphasized in warnings at the top of the module's documentation:

> Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator .... [which], being completely deterministic, is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes.
>
> [...]
>
> **Warning:** The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes. For security or cryptographic uses, see the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module.

As suggested, for cryptographically secure random number generation, you should use the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module:

> The [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particular, [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random) module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

For your particular use case, the `secrets` module provides a `secrets.choice` function that works analogously to `random.choice`.

Comment: thank you for clarifying my doubt and suggesting a solution

Answer (score 0):

Like @Brian said, random isn't secure with encrypting. Use the secrets module with the built in `choice` function instead of random. You can also use the string module to shorten your combinations:

```
import string
import secrets


CharLIST = string.digits + string.ascii_letters

def NEW():
  myPass = "".join(secrets.choice(CharLIST) for i in range(50,100))
  return myPass


print(NEW())
```

Comment: You can't substitute `random.randint(50, 100)` with `range(50, 100)`. Those do strictly different things

Comment: thank you for your response but this answer does not work for me so i will not accept this answer